# Validating a Website

Tags: html, validation, web, cross-browser

I have been assigned the task of validating a website. 
I searched the web and found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/web/web_validate.asp) post of w3schools that 
allows validating the HTML, CSS, XHTML, XML, WML of a website.

My question is, is that all the validation we need to do? 
We want our website to be cross-browser and to work well on mobile phones.

Are there any better methods to validate our site?

Thank You.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/
This one is standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, [w3schools is a terrible website](http://w3fools.com/); you'd be better off not using it for anything. For a markup validator, try [this](//validator.w3.org) or [this](//validator.nu). Keep in mind that validation only ensures that your markup is syntactically, and to a certain extent, semantically correct, but does not ensure that it'll render or function how you intend across different browsers, for example. For that, you'll have to do testing yourself.

Comment: Exactly. You must test it yourself on all browsers, devices. Many of top sites can't go with most of validators. Also you must know what you need. 100% same view for all users or ignore some things. For example, custom fonts not working on Opera (css fonts). You can use some javascript solution (slowering browsing and other problems), use only common fonts, or just ignore Opera users. Compromises.

Answer (score 2):

If all you've been told is that you need to "validate" the web site, then you've been given a really bad instruction, because it's nowhere near as complete as it needs to be.

Are you supposed to validate the HTML?  Everything can be perfect in the HTML and CSS, and the site may still not work the same way in different browsers.  A difference in interpretation of HTML/CSS is not necessarily an indication that something is "invalid".

Get better (or more precise) instructions if you can.  Otherwise, make them up, deliver your result, and if it's not what was expected, charge normal consulting rates to do things again once you DO have more precise instructions.

If it's just HTML/CSS validation you're after, the [validator at w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) is the one you should be using.  There are also validator add-ons for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo).

If your goal is equivalent rendering in multiple browsers, the only solution is to test your site in the browsers that are important to you.  Remember that different versions of a browser also count as different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Having a W3 valid structure/mark up doesn't mean, your website will look the same on every browser. There exist a lot of tools and plugins to emulate different resolutions or mobile device, but these often don't do a good job.

The only real way to find out, is to ask people to test it on their device.